# Multi-line UILabel with auto layout, how to adjust font size according to content without changing label's frame?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, autolayout

I have a multi-line `UILabel`, which will display contents at run time, contents may only need 1 line or up to 3 lines.

When there is less contents, I'd like the label using a larger font size, and when there are more contents, I want the label to use multiple lines and smaller font size.

Due to autolayout, I can't set the frame of `UILabel`, and the frame of the label is unknown until run time, so that it can be compatible with different devices.

Currently I set line number of the label as a fixed number, which will divide contents into multiple lines when there is more contents, but when there is less contents, the single line uses a font size as small as when there is more contents. This is not the best experience.

Comment: what if you set num of lines  and font scale factor ?

Comment: @adnan this works like magic, by setting label to multi-line and set the font to a big size and set the auto shrink to minimum font size to a small size, the contents of the label adjust just as the way I want! Would you please describe your comment with more detail as an answer, so that I can accept it as the answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**set num of lines and font scale factor 0.5 or 0.75**

If your content is small it would use the occupied lines and font size will be the actual size. When your content grows these properties will check if with actual fontsize the content can be adjusted to all lines or not. if its not adjustable with full size then font will be scalled to adjust in contentview.